# JavaScript get list of styles currently applied to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

### List *only* rendered styles, not arbitrary ones that aren't applied

I've tried many things to get the styles applied to an element but have come up blank.

Please do not cite `getComputedStyle` as being a solution unless you can solve the junk returns issue.

The primary problem is that `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('ANY ELEMENT')).fill` will return `"rgb(0, 0, 0)"`, which is **not** the correct style in almost any instances, and has no apparent way to destinguish if its actually being applied or not.

The above example is not the only problem case; there are tons of rules returned by `getComputedStyle` which are wrong and will drastically change the look of the page if they are applied.

Static parsing is not an option as there are cases where the .css files are on another server with no cross-origin headers; which also hides styles usually found in `document.styleSheets`.

Is there any way to get a list of the applied styles and nothing else?

**As requested this code will demonstrate the problem (on Chrome):**

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i in all)
    if (all[i].style) all[i].style.cssText = window.getComputedStyle(all[i]).cssText;
```

EDIT: My answer has code which works on all browsers.  I keep above to preserve comment thread.

Comment: This is complicated to do to figure out if a *specific* style is rendered, much less all of them. Google 'how to tell if an html element is visible' for some idea of how much code it takes to even do that much. Every broad category of styles would likely all have weird edge cases. A solution may be possible, but I question whether it would be *practical*. I'll be quite excited though if someone proves me wrong.

Comment: @JaredSmith I've written code that does visibility checks, as well as occlusion checks by simulating how something will be rendered and what elements might be over it.  It's not complicated when the information is avaliable, which in this case I don't believe it is.  The browser is clearly rendering everything on the page so it knows exactly what styles it has applied to yeild the page it is displaying, but it seems there is no API that provides this information (for an unknown reason).

Comment: Complicated? No. I misspoke. Tedious? Yes. `getBoundingClientRect`, `position`, and `z-index` for each element. Calculate overlap and what has an occlusion based on z-index (where relevant). Don't forget about overflow on the parent! Multiply all that by all the display, color, font, size, etc css properties possible. I'd be surprised if it fit in any reasonable-sized amount of js and even more surprised if it had acceptable perf characteristics.

Comment: @JaredSmith What's the point?  Checking if a style is applied should be simple, it's not remotely similar to checking if an element is visible.  It was a fairly large ammount of code to reliably check for visibility but that's totally irrelevant

Comment: You mean you want a list for each style of what the current style with the highest rule precedence is? I misread the question, I thought you wanted which styles were *rendered* (which is why I wondered off into the visibility woods). And I think your original surmise is correct, I'm not sure you can get that info. That's a great feature request though.

Comment: @JaredSmith This really isn't a matter of precedence, that could be simulated.  The problem is the information literally isn't avaliable at all (if it were, you could just simulate it). On domains with cross-server .css styles you may not have access to the stylesheets that are live on the page in any way.

Comment: Can you show us how the getComputedStyle go wrong with a sample? https://jsfiddle.net/6wL6n83s/1/ , if the element haven't set the fill (or not svg element), it is correct to show "rgb(0, 0, 0)" since it will calculated all the attribute although you haven't set it (use default or inherited).

Comment: @KitFung `"fill: rgb(0, 0, 0)"` is not default or inherited, all text would be black if that were true.  Try applying every style returned by `getComputedStyle` as an inline style

Comment: fill is the style used for svg element, if it is just text, it will not change the color at all.

Comment: @KitFung I have added code to the question which demonstrates the problem.  I am using Chrome browser, as firefox does not implement the computed style return structure according to spec in this case; though the styles can still be looped and applied if necissary.

Comment: Every style and attribute have the default value. For example, if you haven't set the color of a text, you still can get it "color"/"font-size" value. You can find more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperty)

Comment: @KitFung If you execute my code you will find that this isn't correct.  All text will become black which is not the computed style of the current page.   If `getComputedStyle` returned the proper style nothing would change.  I must note again that Firefox does not implement cssText on the return of getComputedStyle, but you can still apply everything manually and get the same result

Comment: It seem be the problem about parent&children relation or the looping problem. If you try it one by one instead looping all the element, it work correctly.

Comment: @KitFung I think still it is it not possible to get ones which are set.  If I am recording css values: getComputedStyle returns many which are unused and maybe even some which apparently can over-ride the parent style and produce an invalid page. I will try to resolve the correct order to set things and see if this solves the problem.  I will post my code if I solve this

Comment: @KitFung You were almost right.  99% of it seems to be from inherited style problem, but there are still some small issues remaining where the styles are actually wrong (related to line height or something, i'm not sure yet).  I have written code that applies them according to embedded depth.  I will post it as an answer very soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Partial Answer (Updated):

It is possible to get only the active styles by calling my function `getRenderedStyles`:

> *`getRenderedStyles` now bypasses active stylesheets for more accurate output.*

```
function getRenderedStyles(element) {
    var tmpele, tmpstyle, elestyle, varstyle, elecolor, eletag;
    var styles   = {};
    var defstyle = {};
    elestyle   = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    elecolor   = elestyle.color; 
    eletag     = element.tagName;
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    frag.appendChild(document.documentElement);
    tmpele   = document.appendChild(document.createElement(eletag));
    tmpstyle = window.getComputedStyle(tmpele);
    styles['color']     = elecolor===tmpstyle.color?undefined:elecolor;
    tmpele.style.color  = elecolor; // workaround for color propagation on other styles 
    for (var i in tmpstyle)
        defstyle[i] = tmpstyle[i];
    tmpele.remove();
    document.appendChild(frag);
    varstyle = element.style;
    for (var i in varstyle) {
        if ((((typeof varstyle[i])==="string"))&&(i!=="cssText")) {
            if ((defstyle[i]!==elestyle[i]))
                styles[i] = elestyle[i];
        }
    }
    return styles;
}
```

Sadly there's a caviat as the browser still seemingly returns invalid styles in some cases. Often shifting the locations of elements.

To verify this you may run the following code, **which takes into account parent/child inheritance**, in an attempt to properly apply the current styles to the page:

```
function DOMDepth(element) {
    var cur  = element;
    var deep = 0;
    while(cur.parentNode)
        deep++, cur = cur.parentNode;
    return deep;
}

function getElementsByDepth() {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var depth_map = {};
    var deepest   = 0;
    for(var i in all) {
        var depth = DOMDepth(all[i]);
        deepest   = depth>deepest?depth:deepest;
        depth_map[depth] = depth_map[depth] || [];
        depth_map[depth].push(all[i]);
    }
    depth_map['deepest'] = deepest;
    return depth_map;
}

function inlineComputedStyles() {
    var depth_map = getElementsByDepth();
    for (var i = depth_map.deepest; i>0; i--) {
        var elements = depth_map[i];
        for (var j in elements) {
            var styles = getRenderedStyles(elements[j]);
            for (var k in styles) {
                elements[j].style[k] = styles[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the preceeding and can confirm it does not suffer the color problems of the snippet in the question.  Sadly I am uncertain as to why some elements still shift or if there's a way to fix it.

Special thanks to Kit Fung for pointing out the inheritance problem.

Comment: On Kit Fung's answer the deformation appears more random while the deformation when taking depth into account is more uniform. This may be a clue as to the remaining descrepancy

Answer (score 1):

Here are the version that don't need to check depth. 
The problem in your code is the assign of inline style in the previous element will affect the getComputedStyle result of the next result. It mean the value of getComputedStyle is always changing in the loop. You can first store it in an array like this.

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
tmpArr = []
for(var i in all) {
    if (all[i].style) {
        tmpArr[i] = window.getComputedStyle(all[i]).cssText;
    }
}
for(var i in all) {
    if (all[i].style) {
        all[i].style.cssText = tmpArr[i]; ;
    }
}
console.log("finish");
```

You can change `tmpArr[i] = window.getComputedStyle(all[i]).cssText;` to `tmpArr[i] = window.getComputedStyle(all[i]).cssText + "-webkit-text-fill-color:#691099!important";` to test whether it work

It will be slow if you open the inspector since there are too much inline style, but it will solve the problem if all you need is just put the style to be inline style.

Comment: I have added an answer which more accurately satisfies the question and also has test code for the application